# Redshift: create external table returns 0 rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a *text file* **test.txt** located at *s3://myBucket/*, see sample below, using which I want to create an external table in Redshift.
When I select from the table, it returns 0 rows.

```
1,One
2,Two
3,Three

create external table spectrum_schema.test(
Id integer,
Name varchar(255))
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location 's3://myBucket/';

select * from spectrum_schema.test //returns 0 rows
```

> Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by moving the file to s3://myBucket/test